# How to open a Grails shell on the running dev instance

Tags: database, shell, grails

Grails newbie here.

Is there a way to open a Grails `shell` or `console` on the same JVM instance (or at least the same DB) as the current `run-app`?

I'd like to use the shell to test queries and methods, then fix my controller files, then test them in the browser... all of which without lengthy JVM restarts, and all of them against the same set of persisted objects.

Puzzling enough, the default settings don't seem to do so. Every new `shell` command launches its own JVM with its own empty in-memory database, completely separate from the currently running `run-app` instance.

Should I configure my dev mode to use a local MySQL server and `dbCreate = 'update'`?

I'm sure it'd work, but it seems it would defeat the purpose of having a resettable development database. What is the best practice? How do Grails developers open a shell on a running dev instance, to poke around and test bits of code interactively?

I'm sure I'm missing something very basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your application running then you can use the [console plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/console) to get a web based console. However, be sure you disable this in production.

It's very common to use the `dbCreate` setting of `update` for development and generate migrations for production.